# Two Ios devices Countdown is not running same

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, timer, countdowntimer

I'm working on an app that has timmer feature after specific time app become disable. when user login from two devices with the same account timer of both device disturbs due to their mobile time difference.

I have checked true-time Pod but showing some error on the project running or building.

But One thing more if two devices time is changing then again time conflict occurs between two devices.

Please mention your best solution to get the current time even mobile time is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you’re struggling to get the right timer value because users can log in on different time zones, so when you save the hour on one time zone, the hour of the other device, on the other time zone doesn’t match and things get conflicted.

You can simply refer to **UTC** time instead of the time in each time zone, it’s the same in every device, wordwide.

You can use `NSDate` to get it.

Comment: But One thing more if two devices time is changing then again time conflict occurs
between two devices.

Comment: There’s no time conflict as you shouldn’t refer to specific time zones, only UTC. It’s the same value across all devices. Forget about the device’s current time, you shouldn’t use it at all.